# Filter files in QFileSystemModel according to custom logic

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have QFileSystemModel that i want to display using QTreeView. But I need to change how items are displayed in widget according to following logic:
[image]

How can I do this ?
This example is very close to what i'm trying to get, some things might be changed but this is what I need for sure

Comment: Take a look at [QSortFilterProxyModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html).  Specifically the [filterAcceptsRow](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#filterAcceptsRow) and [lessThan](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#lessThan) members.

Comment: @G.M. Looks like that's exactly what I need. Thanks